# How do you set a floating div's width to take up remaining space without pushing other divs down?

Tags: css

For part of a layout I want to make, I want to use three divs, all floating next to each other. The Left and Right have a max-width set, which works fine, but I want the middle div to expand its width to fill the remaining space. To clarify, the left and right divs may have a width of anywhere from 0px to the max-width, depending on what is in each, and I want the middle div to expand its width so that it takes up the rest of the space not used by the divs on either side.

The problem it's having now is that if there is a lot of content in the middle div, it's expanding and pushing the right div off to the next line instead of keeping it up with the other two.

Here's the css I have so far:

```
#left-column {
 width: auto;
 max-width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}

#middle-column {
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

#right-column {
 width: auto;
 max-width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 float: right;
}
```

...and the HTML:
    `<div id="left-column">...</div>

    <div id="middle-column">...</div>

    <div id="right-column">...</div>`

I think that this can be accomplished using a three-column, single-row table, but I absolutely do **NOT** want to use tables - I want to accomplish as much as possible by using pure css.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Classic Floats

If you order it:

```
<div id="left-column"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
<div id="middle-column"></div>
```

and you float the left column left, and the right column right, the middle column should fill in the remaining space. You will have some issues with margins, borders and paddings though.

---

## Flexbox

If you don't need to support older browsers, you can use flexbox. With flexbox, this sort of structure becomes much simpler, and the markup doesn't need to change.

You *will* need to be able to select the parent element, so for the purposes of this demo, the code will be wrapped by `<div class="wrapper">`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
.middle {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The height and widths are added explicitly so that the `<div>`s are visible. With actual content, the columns would automatically adjust.

Comment: You are the bomb. been struggling on that for ages.

Comment: Yet, by using a table with this purpose you have a 100% perfect behavior in all browsers with minimal CSS. Really, I don't get it. Why are tables considered bad for something like this? You're anyway trying to emulate a table with divs and getting trouble in the way...

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo, I don't use Excel to write up a paper, even though it can be awkward to place items consistently in Word. I don't use `<table>`s to mark up content unless it's tabular data. Content comes first. Someday flexbox will be supported well enough to be useful and questions such as this one will no longer be an issue (there will of course be newer issues).

Comment: @zzzzBov: That's the thing I don't get, the part about "unless it's tabular data". In many cases we try to make divs behave like tabular data, and this is a perfect example. Now, you face one situation: You need 3 columns and you want them to behave the same in all browsers, and you need them to behave like columns. Tables have columns and behave better than any other element for columns or rows. So, why are they bad for your layout if your layout depends completely on columns?

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo, Just because you want it to display in columns doesn't mean that the data is [tabular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_%28information%29). Using divs is preferred when there is no cross-column or cross-row relationship.

Comment: Not, this is not correct. Middle column will fill up all the space available, i.e. its width would be the same as the width if its container. Here's the jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/nSxhg/

Comment: @Vanuan, when you pad the right and left sides of the middle div, everything works just fine. It's what I was referring to when I wrote "You will have some issues with margins, borders, and paddings"

Comment: For the mid column to fit the remaining space, instead of floating it make it "overflow:hidden".

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to dredge up an old thread here but I was looking for a solution to my own problem and came across this and I thought I'd better share with Francisco...

Tables are a terrible idea for positioning layout, the main problem is that before a table will show/render in the browser it has to render it's `</table>` tag.

Could you imagine if Facebook's column content used a table for it's layout, it would take ages for it to render anything to the screen when checking your timeline for instance!
Another issue is that tables behave extremely differently in each browser.

Basically: `<table>` for layout = NO!, `<table>` for listing out rows of data or information = YES!