# 100% width of a fluid "auto width" parent

Tags: html, css, css-float, fluid-layout

I'm trying to create a fluid container comprised of 3 elements. The two on the left and right are a fixed width and are fine. The element in the middle resizes to fill any extra space but seems to run behind the outer elements.

Here is where I'm at so far: (concept taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130568/how-do-you-set-a-floating-divs-width-to-take-up-remaining-space-without-pushing))

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="middle">
    <div class="progress">
        This box shouldn't overlap the outer two
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    float: right;
}
.middle {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width:auto;
    height:40px;
}
.progress {
    background:yellow;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle to illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/f6U9p/) You'll notice that the yellow box is the full width of the page and not constrained to the center box.

The middle box will end up being a fluid media player progress bar and needs to display at any size (within reason). How can I place more elements inside the middle container and make them have a maximum width of the parent. I don't want to have to rely on JavaScript for this unless I have to, in which case I can write a solution, I was just wondering if there was a CSS solution?

Comment: add `overflow: auto;` to .middle dunno if that's what you are expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.middle {
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/f6U9p/1/

This will allow the space of the sidebars to be excluded from the width of the middle element.

Comment: Wow, well now I feel like quite the idiot. It's the simple things you miss! Thanks!

Comment: ...And I haven't forgotten to accept, just give me another 5 minutes.

Comment: The padding is a lie!
http://jsfiddle.net/f6U9p/3/ but on a serious note: it will make your content start from the center, yet the element will behave overlapping everything. It's bad for when you profile your middle containers width which will return a width that strays from the one you need (in exactly 300px)

Comment: It's `.progress` itself which I need outside of the outer elements so this fixes my issue, I guess it's something to keep in mind if anyone finds this at a later date and needs something slightly different!

Comment: @Mike86 typically, I'd just set the z-index of the sidebar elements over the center element. If that's your concern, you could use margin instead of padding. Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/f6U9p/4/

Comment: The z-index is irrelevant since i'm talking about implementing logic that needs the exact size of an element. Margin is more accurate indeed.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use display: table and display:table-cell

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="progress">
        This box shouldn't overlap the outer two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">&nbsp;</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
}

.left,.right {
  display: table-cell;
}

.left {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
}

.right {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
}

.middle {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height:40px;
}

.progress {
  background:yellow;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6U9p/2/

Answer (score -1):

Add `float: left` to `.middle.`

The outer divs are floated, so the yellow box is going behind them.